# Normalizing Time Periods to Compare Them

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working on a project where I am trying to compare the number of projects completed in various, discrete time periods. The time periods are categorical (if that matters).

The thing is that each time period has a different number of days and people working on the projects that were completed in that time period.

In order to compare the time periods, I took the number of people working  in each time period and divided that by the largest number of people in any time period to get a people normalizer. I did the same thing for the number of days in each period, dividing the number of days in each period by the number of days in the period with the most days. Thus, these normalizers are on a 0 to 1 scale with the period with the greatest number of people and days having a score of 1.

Then I multiplied the day and people normalizers for each period to get an overall normalizer. I then divided the non-normalized number of projects in each time period by the combined day and person normalizers to get the adjusted, normalized number of projects.

Example

**Period 1**: 65 days. 8 people, 5 projects completed.

**Period 2**: 85 days, 9 people. 6 projects completed.

**Period 3**: 90 days, 10 people, 4 projects completed.

I want to normalize these three periods so that I'm comparing how productive each period was given the number of people and days.

Is this a legitimate way of normalizing these time periods so they can be compared to each other?

Comment: I suggest you give a small example. Also, when you say "compare", what do you want to compare exactly? What units?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here is an example:                                                          Period 1: 65 days. 8 people, 5 projects completed.                                                                                            Period 2: 85 days, 9 people. 6 projects completed.                                                Period 3: 90 days, 10 people, 4 projects completed.                                              I was to normalize these three periods so that I'm comparing how productive each period was given the number of people and days.

Comment: The question is interesting, I suggest you post it on: https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you looking for the productivity of people? Just divide time by number of projects and number of people assuming that the projects have same difficulty level.

Comment: @NoChance Thanks. I may do that!

Comment: @Moti Correct me if I'm wrong, but that calculation gives you the number of days, on average, each person spent on each project. So, assuming each project was the same difficultly level, which they are not, a lower figure for that calculation shows that each person, on average, is more productive with the time allotted to them. That's an interesting calculation, but not what I'm looking for I don't think. I'm looking to compare the productivity of the whole team between periods. I'm looking to compare the total number of projects completed in each period while controlling for days and people.

Comment: You need to weight the project difficulties and take into account.

Comment: @Moti You are totally right. We are going to include that in our data collection methodology going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Project 1.  13 × 8 people days per project.
That is how to rank them, by people days per project.
That is simple and should be sufficient for comparesions.

If you need some complicated ranking number, then
divide the people days per project by some arbitrary
number like m, the maximum people days per project.

If you want higher rating to be better in a limited
economic sense, then use 1 - m, a number you
may want to multiply by 100 for a % like rating.

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. Basically, it seems to me that by performing this calculation that you will get a percentage of how much faster the average project was completed in each period compared to the period where projects were completed the slowest on average. Is that correct? So in the examples I provided above, the largest number of people days used for the average project (225) was period 3 and the lowest was period 1 (104). 104/225 =.46  and 1 - .46 = .54. .54 times 100 = 54. So projects were completed on average 54% faster in period 1 than in period 3. That what you meant?